# \fbox has very thick lines

Tags: fbox

[image]

fbox gives very thick line in sublime text editor with sumatra pdf
but in texmaker with sumatra gives normal thin lines--why is this?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[remember picture, overlay] \draw[line width=1pt] ($(current page.north west)+(1in, -.5in) $)rectangle($(current page.south east)+(-.5in, 1in) $);
\end{tikzpicture}

\fbox{However long the sentence is, it will not break into separate lines.}

\framebox{same as \texttt{\textbackslash fbox}, but more controls}


\centering
\fbox{
\begin{minipage}{.7\linewidth}
Put non-floating objects inside the \texttt{\textbackslash fbox}, e.g., minipages, tabulars, etc.
\end{minipage}
}




\centering
\fbox{
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
$+$ & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{tabular} \hspace{.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc}
$\cdot$ & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{tabular}
}
```

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full but minimal self contained example others can copy and test as is

Comment: Probably `sublime` tries to give a pseudo-preview without actually typesetting the document. Your question is not really related to TeX but rather to the `sublime` editor, so better ask in the [`sublime` forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com/), or check the settings of `sublime`.

Comment: @gernot --roger--done